# Как получить значение тега из html?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть, к примеру, такой HTML код:
`<img alt="HDG" src="s.png"/>`

Учитывая, что `HDG` и `s.png` могут быть абсолютно разными, мне нужно получить в чистом виде строку `s.png`...

PS Видел реализацию чего-то похожего на `BeautifulSoup`, но не могу найти...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Реализация на `Beautiful Soup` - хорошее решение:

Преобразуйте `html` в объект `soup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

и найдите в нем `img` (список всех img, в данном случае):

```
images = soup.find_all('img')
```

ваши `src` и `alt` будут в списке словарей:

```
for image in images:
    alt = image['alt']
    src = image['src']
    print(f'alt: {alt}, src: {src}')
```